# Topic seems unrelated to the rest of the sentence

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

From [this article](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011247651000/k10011247651000.html):

> **学校を経営している会社は**、教育と関係がある会社のほかに、不動産や介護、建設などの会社も増えています。
>   [companies that run schools] Besides companies related to education, companies involved in real-estate, nursing and construction are also increasing.

I cannot parse this sentence. The topic 学校を経営している会社は seems to be unrelated to the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the cultural context that needs to be understood in order to fully comprehend this sentence is that in Japan, it is not rare for companies to start a sideline business that is totally unrelated to its original line of business.  Japanese language schools are often started by non-education-related companies.

> (学校{がっこう}を経営{けいえい}している会社{かいしゃ})(**A**)は、(教育{きょういく}と関係{かんけい}がある会社)
>   (**B**)のほかに、(不動産{ふどうさん}や介護{かいご}、建設{けんせつ}などの会社)(**C**)も増{ふ}えています。

The basic structure of this sentence is:

> "A consists not only of B but also of C."

More specifically,

> "Among A, there is B and additionally, there is also an increasing number of C."

Thus, the topic (A) is perfectly related to the rest of the sentence.

> "Found among the companies that run the (Japanese language) schools (today), are education-related companies and additionally, an increasing number of companies involved in real estate, care for the aged, construction, etc."

Answer (score 1):

Well, the topic (as you have identified) is "companies that run schools"; the sentence is talking about such companies, and says that [these; the topic] are not only companies (directly) related to education, but also increasingly, companies from the real-estate, nursing (or rather, "care workers", I think) and construction.